# How to get countries in North America using REST Countries API

Tags: javascript, api, rest

There seems to be no way of getting countries that belongs to South America or North America since their continent contains two words. I tried the following but I always get a 404 HTTP Status Code:

```
GET https://restcountries.com/v3.1/subregion/northamerica
GET https://restcountries.com/v3.1/subregion/north-america
GET https://restcountries.com/v3.1/subregion/NA
```

etc. The documentation did not specify how to get them. I could filter the NA countries of the response from this request:

```
GET https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/america
```

but that seems to miss the point of a REST API (especially when they included a subregion endpoint in their API).

Comment: https://restcountries.com/v3.1/subregion/north%20america

Answer (score -1):

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
- https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding

Not all characters are able to be a part of the URL as you have noticed in the example above. These characters are generally represented as an encoding in this case `%20` represents space. The links above go into further detail and might help understand why this is the case.

---

I'll reference Robby Cornelissen's answer in the comments as the right answer. You are receiving a 404 status code because the resources you are requesting are not present in the server e.g.

- `restcountries.com/v3.1/subregion/north-america`
- `restcountries.com/v3.1/subregion/northamerica`

are different resources than

- `restcountries.com/v3.1/subregion/north%20america`

To represent `north america` in url format you need to encode the string which results in `north%20america`. The resources help provide more context on url encoding.